# Download link on Paperclip Attachment in Rails_admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, attachment, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` gem together with `Paperclip`. My model looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :asset,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "200x200" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

How can I include a download link into the `index` action? So that, on `admin/products` every entry in the table will have a download link? I read through the documentation, but they don't seem to specify any of these features.

[EDIT]

On my main index action which was routed here: `/products` I used to do:

```
<%= link_to "Download", product.asset.url(:original, false) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Submission model:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Image attachment and validations
  has_attached_file :file,
    :url => "/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/files/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => 'application/pdf'

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do.

`<%= link_to "Download", product.asset(:original) %>` 
or

`<%= link_to "Download", product.asset.url(:original) %>`

They both do the same thing.

If you want to change what version of the image they download just change `:original` to `:medium`, `:small` or `:thumb`.

For Rails Admin do following:

```
config.model "Product" do
  list do
   ....
    field :download do
      formatted_value do
        bindings[:view].tag(:a, href: bindings[:object].assets(:original)) << "Download"
       end
     end
   end
   ...
 end
```

Comment: Should this logic still go under my `submissions/index.html.erb` ?

Comment: I mean, even if I am using the `rails-admin` gem?

Comment: I cannot include that in the admin view, as I don't have a view, so how can I add that link under rails_admin.rb in initializer?